# How can I increment ID after featching it from the array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of array data like:

```
$array = {
    "sections" : {
        "H": {
            "name": "dummy",
            "html": "<div id="dummy">d</div>"
        }
    }
}
```

I am featching the data on click event like this

```
$htmlData = $array["sections"]["H"]['html'];
```

Now what I want : After clicking the button the html comes out (working) and the id dummy will increase everytime on click

By default it is :

```
<div id="dummy">d</div>
```

On first time it remain the same :

```
<div id="dummy">d</div>
```

but on second click it becomes :

```
<div id="dummy--1">d</div>
```

on third click :

```
<div id="dummy--2">d</div>
```

and so on.

```js
$array = {
 "sections" : {
  "H": {
   "name": "dummy",
   "html": "<div id=\"dummy\">d</div>"
  }
 }
}

$(function(){
 $('#cm').click(function(event) {
  $htmlData = $array["sections"]["H"]['html'];
    console.log($htmlData);
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="cm">Click me</button>
```

Comment: How about *change the id value* whenever it is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a counter variable for that and on the second click parse the HTML and update the id attribute and get back the HTML using jQuery.

```js
$array = {
  "sections": {
    "H": {
      "name": "dummy",
      "html": "<div id=\"dummy\">d</div>"
    }
  }
}

$(function() {
  // counter which holds the counts of click
  var count = -1;
  $('#cm').click(function(event) {
    $htmlData = $array["sections"]["H"]['html'];
    // check the count value for second click
    if (++count > 0)
      // in case of not a first click parse the html and generate a jQuery object
      $htmlData = $($htmlData).attr('id', function(i, v) {
        // update the attrubute value
        return v + '--' + count
        // get back the html content from the DOM object
      })[0].outerHTML
    console.log($htmlData);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="cm">Click me</button>
```

Comment: works on click only if the same code I need on hover or drop event

Comment: @user7791702 : instead of `.click(function()` use `.on('click mouseover', function(){`

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep track of the click counts in a variable: `counter` Every time there is a click you increase this counter and change the html accordingly.

```js
var counter = 0;

$array = {
    "sections": {
        "H": {
            "name": "dummy",
            "html": "<div id=\"dummy\">d</div>"
        }
    }
}

$(function() {
    $('#cm').click(function(event) {
        $htmlData = $array["sections"]["H"]['html'];
        console.log($htmlData);
        counter++;
        $array["sections"]["H"]['html'] = "<div id=\"dummy--" + counter + "\">d</div>"
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="cm">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your id be "dummy1" "dummy2" every time on click, just a counter in it, like below

```
var i=0;
$(function(){
    $('#cm').click(function(event) {
        i++;
        $htmlData = $array["sections"]["H"]['html']="html": "<div id=\"dummy"+i+"\">d</div>"
       console.log($htmlData);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$array = {
    "sections" : {
        "H": {
            "name": "dummy",
            "counter": 0,
            "html": "<div id=\"{id}\">d</div>"
        }
    }
}

$(function(){
    $('#cm').click(function(event) {
        var $arr = $array["sections"]["H"],
            $name = $arr.name,
            $counter = $arr.counter,
            $htmlData = $arr.html,
            $id;

        if ($counter > 0) {
            $id = $name + "--" + $counter;
        } else {
            $id = $name;
        }

        console.log($htmlData.replace("{id}", $id));
        $array["sections"]["H"]["counter"] = ++$counter;
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="cm">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much your code is helpful but in not my purpose Thanks once again Seiya